# How to use some special symbols like ™ ,♟, ⚘, ✿,  etc in blender?

Tags: text-object, font

I was facing the problem regarding symbols like ™, ♟, ⚘, ✿,  to be used in blender. Changing the font type to MS Gothic helped to view ™ ♟ ✿ but ⚘ and  symbol is still not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the font **Segoe UI Emoji Standard**, you can find it under the filename **seguiemj.ttf** in the Windows Fonts directory.

EDIT: To get the flower, use **Segoe UI Symbol Standard**, the filename is **seguisym.ttf**. It has all symbols, but the icecream looks different.

Comment:  symbol is visible by Segoe UI but ⚘ is still not

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I overlooked that while trying to find the correct icecream symbol. I've edited my answer.